# 1.5TB hard drive showing as 500Gb

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, disk-space, gpt, diskpart

I have a Samsung `1500GB` hard drive (HD155UI) that started life as a external hard drive. It was later removed from its enclosure and placed in a gaming computer. After this, it was removed from the gaming computer and placed in a different computer. In this last computer the drive showed up as RAW. Using drive recovery software, I was able to recover ~`700GB` of data from it.

After this, I formatted the drive at which point it showed a capacity of `465GB`. There is no unallocated space. I've looked in the BIOS where it also shows up as `465GB`.

[image]

I've tried to convert the drive to GPT using diskpart. None of this has worked.

[image]

Comment: Must be software limitations. What are the OSes of all the mentioned machines?

Comment: Are there any RAIDs involved at the machine that didn't see the full capacity?

Comment: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/5b26c3bf-a4ae-4604-944d-cd1b53bfaecf/windows-7-doesnt-recognize-all-of-a-4-tb-drive?forum=w7itprogeneral

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev: hey, the drive has never been involved in any RAIDs. The screenshots in the question above are from Windows Server 2016

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev; what really throws me is that the disk even shows the size of `465GB` in the BIOS

Comment: According to the MS forum post, it's likely an old BIOS' limitation and/or you need to boot in UEFI mode. Can you update the BIOS?

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev: Would the BIOS limitation be for support of this specific hard drive? Cause as you can see, it detects a `4TB` and `5TB` hard drive just fine. Regardless, I will try updating the BIOS.

Comment: You never told us this machine detects other TB+ drives okay :) Other than that, the drive's internal metadata may have got botched as in http://superuser.com/questions/38047/seagate-1-5tb-hard-drive-shows-only-500gb-size?rq=1 , or some part of it failed - then you need some specialized tools like http://blog.atola.com/restoring-factory-hard-drive-capacity/ and/or customer support. Does it show normal capacity in a machine that previously detected it fine?

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev: sorry, I assumed that the other TB+ drives support would be apparent from the powershell snippet. I've since removed the drive and placed it back into the external enclosure and tried this in a few different machines. Still shows `465GB`. You've provided links to some good sources of information that I will be trying. Thanks

Comment: You never said what exactly is shown in the output (what the command is and e.g. if it's even the specific machine), so I couldn't afford to draw any conclusions. (Btw you shouldn't post text as pictures and copy-paste it instead)

Answer (score 0):

It's *possible,* but not certain, that the disk's [Host Protected Area (HPA)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Host_protected_area) feature has been activated. This feature enables a portion of a disk's space to be hidden from the OS. Unfortunately, I'm not familiar with Windows tools to check and manipulate HPA settings. If you're familiar with Linux, though, you can use the `hdparm` tool and its `-N` option. Pass `-N` no value to view the current settings:

```
$ sudo hdparm -N /dev/sda

/dev/sda:
 max sectors   = 7814037168/7814037168, HPA is disabled
```

If this report, unlike my sample above, shows that HPA is enabled, you can pass the correct value to the tool, preceded by `p`, as in `sudo hdparm -N p7814037168 /dev/sda`, to disable the feature and regain all your disk's space. (The `p` tells `hdparm` to make the change permanent; if it's omitted, the change will be temporary, according to the `hdparm` man page.)